# Why different inferred dtype of pandas.Series with defined index?

Tags: python, pandas

Why do the following 2 statements generate a different dtype?

```
pd.Series({0: 1001, 1: 1002, 2: 1003})

0     1001
1     1002
2     1003
dtype: int64

pd.Series({0: 1001, 2: 1002, 4: 1003}, index=range(3))

0    1001.0
1       NaN
2    1002.0
dtype: float64
```

The second Series replaces the dict index by a new range. I don't see why it should generate a different dtype?

Answer (score 2):

`NaN` is used to represent missing data. `NaN` is also a floating-point value. So for a Series to contain `NaN`, it must have a dtype capable of holding floating-point values (such as `float64` or `object`, but not `int64`).

Comment: see also docs here - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na